# invalid file path while trying to rebuild with apktool and aapt2

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, android-drawable, apktool, aapt2

I am facing an error while try to repack an apk with apkool. below is the error trace.

```
W: error: invalid file path 'C:\Users\ccre\res\drawable2\abc_ic_search_api_material.xml'.
W: error: invalid file path 'C:\Users\ccre\res\drawable2\abc_ic_voice_search_api_material.xml'.
W: error: invalid file path 'C:\Users\ccre\res\drawable2\abc_item_background_holo_light.xml'.
W: error: invalid file path 'C:\Users\ccre\res\drawable2\abc_list_divider_material.xml'.
W: error: invalid file path 'C:\Users\ccre\res\drawable2\abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark.xml'.
brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [C:\Users\HOMA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_3949150857603741809118973406025728052.tmp, compile, --dir, C:\Users\ccre\res, --legacy, -o, C:\Users\ccre\build\resources.zip]
```

Does anyone tell me what is wrong here and why this error **[error: invalid file path]** is shown while the file is there?!

Comment: provide apktool version, please

Comment: @HoBBiT, apktool version **2.4.1**

Answer (score 1):

It seems that APK resources were obfuscated with AndroResGuard. ApkTool can (mostly) decompile it but compilation is performed with standard aapt2 and it does not understand 'drawable2' resource type, so it complains about invalid file path.

You can find more info on this issue here: https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/1719